# Why the answer is not O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am so confused that why the answer is not O(n^2)?
My T(n) is 2 + 2n^2 + n +1 so it should be O(n^2).
But the answer is not.

```
a = 4
b = 10
for i  in range(n):
    for j in range(a):
        total = total + 1
for i in range(b):
    total = total + 1
print(total)
```

Part (a) is wrong: T(n) is a Quadratic function or other nonlinear function

Comment: the inner loop runs a fixed number of times (a=4), so you have 4n Operations there, plus b in the second loop. Remember your only input parameter is n.

Comment: Thank you, so the T(n) = 4n +10?

Comment: actually, you will have 2 assignments, then 4n in the first loop, 10 in the second, and one operation in the last one. so you'll have 4n+13 Operations, which will be O(n). Note that the number of operations done is rarely precisely identifyable and the performance depends highly on the cost of each specific operation, so you'll mostly stay at the O(n) precision level.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the the print() and a = 4, b = 10. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are constant, then this is just `O(n)`. Because only the first `for` loop that runs from `0` to `n` is linear in `n`. Other two for loops require constant amount of work. Total complexity is `O(n*a+b) = O(n)`. It will be different if `a` or `b` are a function of `n`.

Comment: So as a = 4, b = 10, T(n) is 4n + 10 then is O(n), right?

Comment: Yes, it is linear in n.